# After upgrade, Jekyll site no longer generates blog index page

Tags: jekyll

I recently upgraded to Jekyll 2.0.3. I have a site with a blog index page:

```
_layouts/
    [ layouts]
_posts/
    [ posts ]
blog/index.html
index.html
other-stuff.html
```

And I also have `_plugins`, `_includes` etc.

All pages apart from `blog/index.html` generate fine. `blog/index.html` gives me the bare source in the generated folder:

```
--- 
layout: blog
title: My blog
---

{% for post in site.posts limit:5 %}
<div class="blog-summary">
<h2><a href="/{{ post.url }}/index.html">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
<p class="blog-post-date">{{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }} in <a href="/blog/categories/{{ post.category }}/index.html">{{ post.category }}</a></p>
{{ post.content | postmorefilter: post.url, "Read more..." }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried:

- Simplifying the `blog/index.html` to some plain text. The page is just the same, but with the text instead
- Using `-t` switch on the build command. Nothing is output
- Using the `watch` command. Again, no different.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Save the page without BOM.

Chances are the BOM is appearing before the initial front-matter, causing Jekyll to pass over it.

Comment: Interesting idea. This worked with Jekyll <v1 and indeed still does. Did something change?

Comment: I had the same issue happen to me and I spent a few hours looking over the diffs but didn't find anything that would suggest anything changed. Obviously something *had* to change, but what it is I can't find and my issue that I raised on the GH repo returned basically nothing except for what I said in my answer above :/